# Custom Desktop Change Wallpaper Interval on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, background, applescript, intervals

I want to be able to change the background of my desktop every 10 seconds in a random order. I like using pages of manga as a background and 5 seconds is too short. Can someone help me figure out how to customize the time. I read another article on this same situation, however, the code they provided wouldn't work for me. I have only just discovered AppleScript so I do not know what I am doing. I figured that the code is not tailored to my needs and requires modifications that I cannot seem to figure out.

```
tell application "System Events"
 -- RANDOM ROTATION OF A FOLDER OF IMAGES
 tell current desktop
 set picture rotation to 1 -- (0=off, 1=interval, 2=login, 3=sleep)
 set random order to true
 set pictures folder to file "Mac OS X:Library:Desktop Pictures:Plants:"
 set change interval to 5.0 -- seconds
 end tell
end tell
```

I have changed "Mac OS X:Library:Desktop Pictures:Plants:" to "Macintosh HD:Users:jonathan:Desktop:Wallpaper:"

and received "System Events got an error: Can’t set file "Macintosh HD:Users:jonathan:Desktop:Wallpaper:" of current desktop to file "Macintosh HD:Users:jonathan:Desktop:Wallpaper:" of current desktop."

I want to use the folder called "Wallpaper" on my desktop if this helps.

I appreciate the help. Sorry for my lack of knowledge or poor question structure.

Here is a link to original question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103833/can-i-have-a-custom-desktop-wallpaper-change-picture-interval

Answer (score 2):

Use this it will work and take Particular folder as picture

```
tell application "System Events"
    -- RANDOM ROTATION OF A FOLDER OF IMAGES
    tell current desktop
        set pictures folder to "Mac OS X:Library:Desktop Pictures:Plants:"
        set picture rotation to 1 -- (0=off, 1=interval, 2=login, 3=sleep)
        set random order to true
        set change interval to 5.0 -- seconds
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the folder and then run this script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current desktop
        set change interval to 10
    end tell
end tell
```

It seems like the setting sticks, although I'm not sure if it says across reboots or after modifying any of the Desktop settings. You may need to rerun the command as needed.